# Ember Nested Urls as single request

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to have nested urls in Ember that make a single request vs multiple requests?

My url looks like this

/clients/:client_id/claims/:claims_id/lines/:line_id

The routes are nested in the ember router as well to match.

What im trying to do is not make 6 requests when I may only need 1

and also when I manually change the :line_id in the url it doesnt update the DOM with the new record. Shouldnt it?

The Router

```
Nucleus.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource("clients", { path: 'clients' }, function () {
    this.resource("client", { path: ':client_id' }, function () {
      this.resource("claims", function () {
        this.resource('claim', { path: '/:claim_id/:claim_sub' }, function () {
          this.resource('lines', function () {
            this.resource('line', { path: ':line_id' }, function () {
              this.resource('flags', function () {
                this.resource('flag', { path: ':flag_id' });
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
  this.route("errors", { path: '/errors/:error_id' });
});
```

My routes look like so

```
Nucleus.ClientsRoute = Nucleus.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return Nucleus.Client.find('clients');
  }
});

Nucleus.ClientRoute = Nucleus.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return Nucleus.Client.find('client', params);
  }
});

    Nucleus.ClaimsRoute = Nucleus.Route.extend({
      model: function (params) {
        var client = this.modelFor('client'),
            clientId = client.get('data.id');

        params.client_id = clientId;
        return Nucleus.Claim.find('claims', params);
      },

      goToNextClaim: function (claim) {
        this.transitionTo('claim', claim);
      }
    });

    Nucleus.ClaimRoute = Nucleus.Route.extend({
      model: function (params) {
        var client = this.modelFor('client'),
            clientId = client.get('data.id');

        params.client_id = clientId;
        return Nucleus.Claim.find('claim', params);
      }
    });

Nucleus.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  setupController: function () {
    this.controllerFor('meta_property').set('model', Nucleus.MetaProperty.find('meta_property'));
    this.controllerFor('header').set('model', Nucleus.User.find("user"));
  }

});
```

And controllers are like so

```
Nucleus.ApplicationController = Nucleus.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['meta_property'],

  isErrorPage: false,

  currentPathDidChange: function () {
    if (this.get('currentPath') === 'errors') {
      this.set('isErrorPage', true);
    } else {
      this.set('isErrorPage', false);
    }
  }.observes('currentPath')

});

Nucleus.ClaimController = Nucleus.ObjectController.extend({});
Nucleus.ClientController = Nucleus.ObjectController.extend({});
```

Comment: can you show your Routes and Controller? Your setup us not completely clear...

Comment: I updated the original post. Is there also a way to run these requests in parallel?